# EFI logs for logging

Tags: boot, logs, uefi

Is it possible to get some logs about (U)EFI boot?

Because I have a Linux entry, who used to work, but since a crash I can't boot anymore on the OS. And the OS is totally fine in chroot. So I need to know what blocks the computer from booting that entry

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fnBfFC8S5D/ Here's one with the ISO. One without ISO will come when I'll understand how to use a PPA in Arch. I don't use any of the Windows entries, since there's no functional Windows in my drive pool. I don't use .efi files or GRUB to boot, but directly the UEFI to boot the Arch kernel (EFISTUB I think, see boot entries)

Comment: No need to run ppa now. Its just if there are updates to Boot-Repair, the ppa is often more current as ISO not rebuilt as frequently. Do not know Arch nor its method of booting. And Boot-Repair's fix is to reinstall grub which you do not want anyway. But with your syslinux boot, is /boot also the ESP? With Ubuntu the ESP is mounted at /boot/efi & is /EFI/ubuntu or /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu and that is just for a grub configfile to find full grub & kernels in /boot a Linux formatted partition. Or separate (ESP) FAT32 & (/boot) ext4 partitions.

Comment: I don't think I will give you more informations than the report. I use vmlinuz and initramfs like you see in the boot entry. I directly boot from that in the UEFI. I don't even know if im using or ever used what is on sda2 (/boot/ with all the .efi files and things). But if I can create a grub at /efi/boot/bootx64.efi as a fallback, you can maybe tell how to, so I can use it as a fallback in case of

Comment: See examples here of "UEFI Hard Drive" entries to UEFI using efibootmgr. https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win Some UEFI do want specific names, most and all should allow any name withing length constraints.

Answer (score 0):

For unknown reasons vmlinuz and initramfs has vanished from ESP

So I deleted /lib/module/$archKernel, I installed `filesystem` `linux` and `linux-headers`, I runned `mkinitcpio` specifying specificly the kernel and the destination. And it worked

It doesn't reply to the question, but it was my solution

BONUS: nVidia drivers wasn't working, no GUI could boot. I reinstalled `nvidia`, it created nvidia files in /lib/modules, and it worked